# How to get the tensor of a layer from the name

Tags: python, tensorflow

In order to re-use some hidden layers of a DNN model, I would like to get the tensor of a hidden layer

Here I have a simple example of what I want to do:

```
import tensorflow as tf

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
  X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 28*28), name="X")
  y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None), name="y")
  dnn = X
  he_init = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()
  for idx, n_hidden in enumerate([10, 10, 10]):
    dnn = tf.layers.dense(dnn, n_hidden, name="hidden{}".format(idx), kernel_initializer=he_init, activation=tf.nn.relu)

  logits = tf.layers.dense(dnn, 5, name="outputs", kernel_initializer=he_init)

  hidden = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("hidden1:0")
```

In the `get_tensor_by_name` function if I give X instead of `hidden1` it works but not with hidden1.

I also to call the `get_tensor_by_name` after running the training (not shown here).

TensorFlow is reporting that the operation, `hidden1`, does not exist in the graph.

What am I doing wrong? How am I suppose to get a hidden layer in order to re-use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `tf.layers` calls internal variables differently. 
To be able to view it, just print global variables like this

```py
...
logits = tf.layers.dense(dnn, 5, name="outputs", kernel_initializer=he_init)        
print(tf.global_variables())
hidden = ...
```

You'll see, that tensor you're trying to get is called `hidden1/kernel:0`. Change the name and it'll be ok

```
tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('hidden1/kernel:0')
```

Comment: Thx indeed it's not crashing anymore. But I am not sure that getting just the kernel is what I want since I want to reuse the layer. If I just get the kernel then I will be missing the bias no?

Comment: If you call name with :number, it's a particular tensor. If you call just name like `hidden1` it's an operation that creates tensors. For reuse I think the easiest way will be to use name scope. If you wrap this call in `with variable_scope('hidden1)` it will use all operations inside, biases, kernels and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. It seems that another workaround is to do the activation separated so then you just have one tensor to get